# How do I lock to a page in viewpager?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to have my app lock to a page on a button press. I have 3 pages that can be swiped between and a forth that can only be accessed by button press. I do this by setting the getCount to 4, but then you can still swipe to the other pages, I want the app to be locked to four until a button press.

here is my code:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new FragmentRecord();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new FragmentCalc();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new FragmentAccounts();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new FragmentSettings();
                    break;
            }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (showSettings) {
            return 4;
        } else {
            return 3;
        }

    }

}



public void settingsButton(View view) {
    showSettings = true;
    View scrollbar = (View) findViewById(R.id.headerSlider);
    scrollbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `ViewPager` class which is possible to control its swipe action:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class ViewPagerSwipeControlled extends ViewPager {

    private boolean swipeEnabled = true;

    public ViewPagerSwipeControlled(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ViewPagerSwipeControlled(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setSwipeEnabled(boolean swipeEnabled) {
        this.swipeEnabled = swipeEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return swipeEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (swipeEnabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

In your layout xml:

```
<com.myapp.view.ViewPagerSwipeControlled
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

to enable and disable swipeability:

```
ViewPagerSwipeControlled viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

...
viewPager.setSwipeEnabled(false);

...
viewPager.setSwipeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Where in my layout do I put the code? Does it go in the activity_main.xml?

Comment: Everywhere you are using `ViewPager` in xml, use `ViewPagerSwipeControlled` instead.

Comment: So if you have `ViewPager` in activity_main.xml, replace it with `ViewPagerSwipeControlled`.

Comment: I am getting an error in my xml saying. Missing classes, and says this is the class android.support.v4.view.ViewPagerSwipeControlled

Comment: Where do you create `ViewPagerSwipeControlled`? You should concatenate its package address before its name. Look at the example that I provided in answer. I assume that the class is in `com.myapp.view` package, so I added `com.myapp.view.ViewPagerSwipeControlled`.

Comment: I have it set up and working now except I can't enable swiping it is always disabled.

Comment: I have updated the `ViewPagerSwipeControlled` class. (In detail, I have updated its `onTouchEvent` method) Please test it again by calling `viewPager.setSwipeEnabled(true);` to enable its swipe.

Comment: I'm happy that the problem is solved. Thank you too.